# Identity matrix properties

Tags: matrices

Is this following equality correct $${\bf a^* I a} = {\bf a^*a}$$

where ${\bf a }$ is $n\times 1$ and ${\bf I}$ is the identity matrix...

Thanks

Comment: Of course, $\bf Ia=a$, so it is immediate that $\bf a^T(Ia)=a^Ta$ and $\bf a^*(Ia)=a^*a$

Comment: Why isn't * defined in the legend that explains a and I then?

Comment: yup correct thats it

Comment: @JBKing: Look carefully: OP writes "$\bf a^*$", not "$\bf a*$", so the asterisk is being used as a superscript, not a cheap replacement for a multiplication symbol.

Comment: relax yall i meant conjugate transpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  It's due to the fact that matrix multiplication is associative.  So

$${\bf a^* I a} = {\bf a^* (I a)} = {\bf a^*(a)} = {\bf a^*a}$$

Comment: Why invoke associativity? Can't you just say $\mathbf{a^*I} = \mathbf{a^*}$?

Comment: @GFauxPas You could also do it by $(a^*I)a=a^*a$, but you need *some* rule for figuring out what the product of $3$ matrices is and associativity is such a rule.